# Fastest Method for Retrieving a File Structure (unix shell)

Tags: shell, find

Okay, so I know that I can use find to return files in a directory (and nested directories) that match various criteria. However, if I want to return all files with no matching of any kind, then are there any faster alternatives?

i.e - I want to return all files within a directory (and nested directories) without performing any kind of filtering; is there a faster way to do this?

When I say return files, I mean anything that isn't a directory, and with no following of symbolic links (though they should be included in the result).

I'm working with a huge (1,000,000+ files) structure, and find takes at least 15 minutes to complete with no criteria other than ! -type d, but this is much too slow, so I'm hoping there are alternatives that I can try.

Comment: I am really just asking because you haven't exactly stated why you are doing this - you are not outputting the list to your terminal, right? If you do, this slows it down horrendously. I am pretty sure you are not doing that since it wouldn't make much sense, but just to be on the safe side.

Comment: Since you don't want links (and presumably other "special" files), rather than using `! -type d`, use `-type f`. Beyond that, the only way you could make it more efficient would be essentially to re-code `find` in C or something, which would likely not gain much. No matter what tool/code you use, walking a tree that size is going to be extremely I/O intensive and take some time (much worse if it's on slow media like a CD/DVD or on a network share).

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth You're probably right on that - since the time is going to be dominated by I/O waiting, the CPU usage difference for `! -type d` compared to `-type f` or `\( -type f -o -type l \)` will probably not be noticable. I was thinking of other types of files he would want to exclude (named sockets, doors, device nodes, etc.), but on second thought, it's highly likely there aren't any of those in his case... And yes, the `stat()` on each entry is pretty much required to tell what kind of object it is(n't)...

Comment: @twalberg I deleted my comment since it felt wrong to compare the unequivalent `! -type d` and `\( -type f -o -type l \)`. Silly race condition :-) But yes, my point is still valid I think. If there is a difference it is negligible, since my guess is what is costly is the `stat`, not so much checking its returned struct. It might still be worth checking the `find` source, maybe he can get some inspiration on stuff to strip, since even a 10% increase might help with these dimensions.

Comment: this belongs on http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Adrian; not to my terminal no, I'm outputting the structure to a file that I can then pass into another program that needs to run later on (I can't pipe the results in directly). I was really just wondering if there's a lower-level command I can use to just grab a file-hierarchy for an entire directory. I'm not sure changing parameters will speed up find much, as it presumably needs to stat the files regardless of what filters I use, in order to see if it's a directory or not for diving into?

Comment: @Haravikk Exactly. Can you elaborate a bit on the whole thing? How often do you need to generate this list, how often does the directory structure change, etc.?

Comment: Filesystem and how your layout looks (rather flat, deeply nested, lots of files per subdirectory) might also be of interest.

Comment: Basically I have a fast method for rsync only changed files to a target folder (without having to leave rsync to do it which can take a long time). However, since the backups are incremental I still need to generate hard-links to the previous backup, without linking deleted files. The advantage of building and sending a list is that the linking can be done by the receiver rsync only, but the list needs to be generated. ~15 minutes is still faster than directly using rsync each time, I was just hoping to cut that down further; however it's still the full structure I need each time.